# Converting an iPhone app to Universal in Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, ipad, universal

I could use a little clarity here.
I've opened a project that is a completed iPhone app. Then selected the target, selected "Universal" from the Summary/Devices dropdown, and followed the prompt to "Make a Universal App."
Xcode created a folder "iPad" with the file "MainWindow-iPad.xib" within.
Fine.

Now I duplicated all of my other nib files, and added "-iPad" after their name. I.e. "MySpecialVC.xib" was duped and renamed "MySpecialVC-iPad.xib." The thought was that Xcode knows some zoodoo about finding the correct xib for the device.
Not so fine.

Then I read that the "-iPad" had to be "~ipad" (tilde, then lower-case ipad). This solved the problem with some of the xibs, **but not all of them**.

Dang if I can't figure this out. Is there a RIGHT way to do this?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to "accept" an answer.

Comment: There is a check mark next to the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I create a new universal project, I get this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

So it's clear the code is explicitly choosing a xib file. Is this not the case for your project?

Comment: Thanks. Yep, that is clear when I'm building a universal from scratch. But in many cases I'm converting a finished iPhone app with many xibs. The duplicate/rename with ~ipad/edit for iPad seems to work OK, just not consistently. Some xibs just are not recognized during the build.