# Converting an iphone app to universal app

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4.5

I have created a iphone app at the begining.But now I want to change it to universal app.In converting it I have changed the target to universal.Gone through google and found I have to create different xibs for ipad.When I change to it to universal it asked me to create a MainWindow for ipad .I clicked Yes.Now on my application launch I get a tabbarController .So I have created a ViewController.xib for ipad which was linked in tabbarController.
BUt I get error [ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key delegate.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {


       ViewController *first=[[ViewController alloc]
                                  initWithNibName:@"ViewController-iPad" bundle:nil] ;


        Login *second=[[Login alloc]initWithNibName:@"Login" bundle:nil];
        second.title=@"Login";
        NSArray *viewArray=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: first,second,nil];
        UITabBarController *tabBarController1=[[UITabBarController alloc] init];
        [tabBarController1 setViewControllers:viewArray animated:NO];

        for(UIViewController *tab in  tabBarController1.viewControllers)

        {
            [tab.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                    [UIFont fontWithName:@"TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT" size:16.0], UITextAttributeFont, nil]
                                          forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        [self.window addSubview:tabBarController1.view];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        CGRect  rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        [self.window  setFrame:rect];
        [viewArray release];
        [first release];
        [second release];
        return YES;

    }

    else
    {
        //code to load tabbarController for  iphone xib's
```

Where to link ?I dont find any outlets when I click FilesOwner?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211636/converting-an-iphone-app-to-universal-in-xcode-4?rq=1

Comment: Make a new project file